# Error while executing .exe result of my code but no when executing it in the debugger

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2008, executable

I have a problem regarding the result of my program. I have a bi winforms application that makes a lot of things. One of them is visualizing a bunch of data I have stored in several .txt files in a given directory. It takes one, read it, close it and then visualize it before reading the next one.

My problem is that if I just execute the program, tell it the directory of the files and ask for visualizing, after reading 2 or 3 files it crashes because a memory access violation. But if I reproduce the exact steps while executing from the debugger of visual studio there is not any error nor warning nor nothing, it just works fine.

I know that the debugger is exactly that, a debugger, and thing execute differently in a debugger, but I dont have any idea why this happens.

Any idea why my program crashes? Or what should I do for avoiding a crash?

I know my question may be too ambiguous, but I don't have other method to show you my problem, unless you want me to post a 20.000 lines code :) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try using ADPlus. It comes as part of the Debugging Tools for Windows suite. It's very easy to use and you get a .hdmp and .mdmp that you can use in WinDBG (in same suite) after the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the debugger after the crash (JIT debugging).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks! But I am a little bit noob in here hehe... following you link I got to "How to: Enable JIT..." and I dont understand hot to enable it... This is what I dont get how to do it: "Set the jitDebugging value in the machine.config or application.exe.config file, located in the system.windows.forms section to true." Can you give me a hand in here?

Comment: I have JIT debugging enabled in the proyect configuration window. May be that it doesnt work because it is a Winfroms application?